# Не получается получить постоянный access токен vk api

Tags: php, api, вконтакте

Необходимо получить постоянный access token в vk api, но при формирование ссылки для получения ([https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=айди&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,friends,groups&response_type=token&v=5.52](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,friends,groups&response_type=token&v=5.52)

выдается ошибка

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"invalid scope"}

причем без параметра scope = offline все работает, в чем дело?

Answer (score 2):

При создании приложения убедитесь что его тип "Standalone-приложение". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]